# Putty keyboard mapping

Tags: putty

I'm using putty to ssh to a unix server
I can't see any colours is one major annoyance
also, if I press home/end, backspace etc it doesn't work.

I tried changing the Keyboard configuration, but none of the combinations I tried worked.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type of server?  Linux?  Solaris?  Something else?

For each key, the aim is to have `tput <key name>` produce the same output as pressing
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> `<key>`.

1. Log on to your server
2. Run `echo $TERM`

   - it should say `xterm` or `putty`
3. Run `tput kbs | cat -v`

   - if it says `^H`, change PuTTY settings so backspace sends `^H`
   - if it says `^?`, change PuTTY settings so backspace sends `^?`
   - if it prints an error message, and you have `TERM=putty`, run `TERM=xterm` and try again
4. Run `tput khome | cat -v`

   - tell us the output and we can figure out which setting you need

See [Configuring PuTTY](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#4.4.1) for some hints and more details.

Comment: server is Solaris (SunOS,Sun-Fire-V215), 
tput kbs | cat -v  gave ^H, I set putty backspace to ^H, backspace is working now, but the delete key is still showing ~
khome kbs | cat -v gave ^H, I set the Home and End keys to rxvt, home is working now, end is not doing anything.
I have the Functions Keys and keypad set to XtermR6, the keypad (i.e. when I switch off the Num Lock) seems to be working ok